# Div responsivo com imagem e outros elementos dentro

Tags: html, css, div, layout-responsivo

Estou criando um *site* *mobile* com *design* responsivo.

Dentro de uma `div` tenho um *slideshow* que mostra imagens 300x300, eu preciso tornar esse *slideshow* responsivo sem mexer nos atributos `width` e `height` dele. O código é mais ou menos esse:

```
<div id="div-de-fora">
    <div id="div-do-slideshow">
        [elementos do slideshow]
    </div>
</div>


//css
#div-do-slideshow{
    width:300px;
}

#div-de-fora{
    ?????
}
```

Mexer no `width` do `#div-do-slidshow` não é possível, visto que ele usa o atributo `left` para trocar as imagens.

É possível alterar a exibição do *slideshow* usando apenas CSS, parâmetros, etc. No `#div-de-fora`?

Já tentei usar `iframe` e FlexBox mas não tive sucesso.

Nesse projeto não estou usando jQuery, a solução deve usar apenas HTML, CSS e JavaScript puro.

Answer (score 1):

Olá. É possível que você consiga o que quer invertendo a ordem de "prioridade". Para tornar o slideshow responsivo eu recomendo não deixá-lo com valores exatos (como 300px). Eu faria algo mais ou menos assim (se eu entendi bem...)

HTML:

```
<div id="div-de-fora">
    <div id="div-do-slideshow">
       <div class="slideshow-wrapper">
           [elementos do slideshow]
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sempre é bom você manter o elemento que manipula o slideshow o mais livre possível de interferências de CSS e Javascript. Nesse caso, eu usaria o `.slideshow-wrapper` para executar o slide, e a div `#div-do-slideshow` para receber a responsividade.

No CSS, eu faria assim:

```
#div-de-fora {
  width: 100%; /* ou 300px */
  height: 300px;
}

#div-do-slideshow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#div-do-slideshow .slideshow-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#div-do-slideshow .slideshow-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* redimensiona imagens automaticamente */
}
```

Dessa maneira, você manipula com valores exatos somente a `#div-de-fora`, podendo até passar valores de `width`/`height` por Javascript. O restante dentro dela vai seguir livremente.

Seria interessante você mostrar seu código do slider.

Answer (score 1):

Coloque essa linha abaixo dentro da tag `<head>` de seu html

Se você quer seu site responsivo , isso resume tudo.

talvez funcione, mas se não ficar do jeito que você quer, você pode alterar o CSS parar `%` em vez de `px`

```html
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Além da `viewport`, é bom colocar um elemento CSS assim:  `* { max-width: 100%; }` que vai assegurar que **nenhum** elemento ultrapasse o tamanho do elemento-pai.

Comment: `viewport` é uma mão na luva kkk, mas realmente tem que alterar os `px` para `%`

Answer (score 1):

Quando se trata de *Layout responsivo*, vale a pena tratar ***basicamente*** o seguinte:

**Viewport**:

> O viewport é a área onde seu website aparece. É a área branca da janela quando você abre o browser. O viewport sempre vai ter o tamanho da janela. Mas a forma como os elementos são renderizados vai depender bastante do dispositivo.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

---

**CSS -** `box-sizing`**:**

> Quando você define `box-sizing: border-box;` em um elemento, os valores do `padding` e do `border` não são adicionados em sua largura.

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

---

**CSS -** `max-width`**:**

> `max-width` irá limitar o tamanho do elemento baseando-se no *elemento-pai*.

```
* { max-width: 100%; }
```

No caso do *Layout responsivo*, não queremos que nada ultrapasse o tamanho da tela, né?!

---

Agora é só aplicar tudo isso ao seu projeto e "*voalá*"!